# How to get data that are enabled in previous year but not in current year

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a table `Accessibility` that contains columns `enable`, `version_id`, and `year`. I want to query and get all versions that are enabled in year 2018 but not in 2019.

But I don't know how to query this.

Comment: Just 2018 or up to 2018?

Comment: just 2018.............

Comment: Is year just an integer/string or a date?

Comment: @Mereghost its integer

Comment: I gather that you also have a Version object (and `versions` table) by the existence of the `version_id` column. am I correct?

Answer (score 0):

You can first build a subquery for versions that are enabled in 2019:

```
subquery = Accessibility.where(year: 2019, enable: true).select :id
```

and then, use that subquery in your query:

```
Accessibility.where("year = 2018 AND enable = true AND id Not IN (?)", subquery)
```

Comment: I need which enable in 2018 but not in 2019